# operate - of two array values?

Tags: php, arrays

operate `-` of two array values?

I Have 02 arrays:

```
$before =
array("a"=>400,
  "b"=>500,
  "c"=>600
);

  $after = 
  array("a"=>100,
      "b"=>100,
      "c"=>100
  );
```

I want to get the result like this:

```
  $now = 
   array(
        "a"=>300,//400-100
        "b"=>400,//500-100
        "c"=>500 //600-100
  );
```

EDIT:

Some elements of $after can be missing

example:

```
$after = 
      array("a"=>100,
          "c"=>100
      );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$now = array();

foreach ( $before as $k => $v ) {
    $a = empty($after[$k]) ? 0 : $after[$k];
    $now[$k] = $v - $a;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use [array_map](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) :

```
$before = array(
    "a"=>400,
    "b"=>500,
    "c"=>600
);

$after = array(
    "a"=>100,
    "b"=>100,
    "c"=>100
);
function dif($a, $b) {
    return $a - $b;
}
$res = array_map("dif", $before, $after);
print_r($res);
```

**output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 300
    [1] => 400
    [2] => 500
)
```

Comment: @IEnAk: Yes it is, you will obtain 600 in the third element of the res array.

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach ($before as $key=>$value) {
    $now[$key] = $value-$after[$key]
}
```

This is valid if you have exactly the same elements in the two arrays.

Answer (score 1):

```
function subtract_arrays($a, $b){
    if(count($a) != count($b)){
        return false;
    }
    $c = array();
    foreach($a as $k=>$v){
        $c[$k] = $a[$k]-$b[$k];
    }
    return $c;
}

$now = subtract_arrays($before, $after);
```