# Operation value of multiple array that have the same key

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I Have an array of array

```
array(4) {
      [0]=>
      array(3) {
        ["a"]=>float(1000)
        ["b"]=>float(3)
        ["c"]=>float(500)
      }
      [1]=>
      array(3) {
        ["a"]=>float(1000)
        ["b"]=>float(852)
        ["c"]=>float(500)
      }
      [2]=>
      array(3) {
        ["a"]=>float(1000)
        ["b"]=>float(5)
        ["c"]=>float(500)
      }
      [3]=>
      array(1) {
        ["e"]=>float(1000)
      }
    }
```

The result will sum all the value that the same keys,so result should be:

```
$result = 
  array(
      "a" =>3000,
      "b"=>900,
      "c"=>1500,
      "e"=>1000
  )
```

Anybody could help me todo this.

thanks.

Comment: You asked this question and you accepted an answer just 15 hours ago. The only difference is that you're adding instead of subtracting. Why ask again, or can't you figure out how to add rather than subtract numbers?

Comment: possible duplicate of [operate - of two array values?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5328623/operate-of-two-array-values)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Pseudo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudocode):

```
result <- new array                       # array holding result
foreach entry1 in array:                  # iterate outer array
    foreach entry2 in entry1:             # iterate each inner array
        if not exists result[entry2.key]: # if key is not already in result...
            result[entry2.key] = 0        # ... add key and set value to zero
        result[entry2.key] += value       # increment result for key with value from inner array
```

<sup>(I'll leave the implementation as an exercise for OP.)</sup>

Answer (score 3):

The trick for this is *ofcourse* to do some sort of iteration over your data, using those string-keys as identifiers. One way of approaching it would be using 2 nested foreaches ( one over the container, one over the individual keys and collecting the data in a central array:

```
$results = array();
foreach ($array as $elements)
{
        foreach ($elements as $key => $value)
        {   
                if (!isset($results[$key]))
                        $results[$key] = 0;

                $results[$key] += $value;
        }   
}
```

A different way would be to have PHP iterate for you:

```
$results = array();

array_walk_recursive(
        $array,
        function($value, $key) use (&$results) {
                if (!isset($results[$key]))
                        $results[$key] = 0;

                $results[$key] += $value;
        }
);
```

Answer (score 2):

This little function will do the job for you.

```
function SummarizeFosArray($array) {
    $results=array();
    foreach ($array as $a) {
      foreach ($a as $k=>$v) {
        $results[$k]+=$v;
      }
    }
    return $results;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code

```
$array = array(
        array('a' => 1000, 'b' =>3, 'c'=> 500),
        array('a' => 1000, 'b' =>852, 'c'=> 500),
        array('a' => 1000, 'b' =>5, 'c'=> 500),
        array('e' => 1000)
        );

$result = array();  

foreach($array as $arr)
{
    foreach($arr as $a => $val){
        $result[$a] += $val;
    }
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($result);
echo "</pre>";
```

Your Result

```
Array
(
    [a] => 3000
    [b] => 860
    [c] => 1500
    [e] => 1000
)
```

Answer (score -1):

use [`array_walk_recursive()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php) function. checkout the PHP manual for details.

Comment: you can't just code everything for everyone. You must show them some way to achieve it. Give a man a fish and he will eat for a day. Teach a man to fish and he will eat for a lifetime.

Comment: I agree with you on this. That's why I upvoted @jensgram. But if the OP cannot solve (and I do not mean to hurt anyone, this is a question site, so this is OK) such a basic problem, what will he do with a link to `array_walk_recursive`?

Comment: Teach this man to fish, and you'll be teaching him again inside 15 hours... this is an almost exact duplicate of his previous question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5328623/operate-of-two-array-values

Comment: Sorry for that @Mark Baker,I am not programmer or developer.but I found stackoverflow is places that I can learn from all of you even your blame. :) thanks