# Need to combine the key's values of two arrays only containing integers

Tags: php

I have two associated arrays containing keys pointing to different values. I want to combine the key's values of the different arrays by summing them (they're all integers). For example I want to turn these two arrays:

`array_1(100=>3, 50=>10, 60=>30)
array_2(100=>10, 60=>50)`

the result would be as following:

`array_combined(100=>13, 50=>10, 60=>80)`

Hope you guys can help me along.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1496682/how-to-sum-values-of-the-array-of-the-same-key

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5336460/operation-value-of-multiple-array-that-have-the-same-key#1

Comment: Thanks! I tried googling almost everything but couldn't find a post regarding this question.